# Python: Find dict in array based on value of key

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Here is my array of `dicts`

```
[{'task': 'send-email', 'email': {'id': 1234}},
{'task': 'send-alert', 'email': {'id': 4567}}]
```

I have a method:

```
def get_side_effect(self, type):
```

I am trying to loop through each `dict` in the array and find the `dict` where the `task` key contains the value of the type passed into the method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
def get_side_effect(self, key):
    return [cdict for cdict in my_list if cdict["task"] == key]

print obj.get_side_effect("send-email")
```

**Output**

```
[{'task': 'send-email', 'email': {'id': 1234}}]
```

**Suggestion** Don't name your variables as `type`, since that would shadow the builtin [`type`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type) function.

But, if all you are going to do is to iterate over the result, you can simply do this

```
for mathched_dict in (cdict for cdict in my_list if cdict["task"] == key):
    print mathched_dict
```

Or you can convert that to a list, with the builtin [`list`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list) function, like this

```
list(cdict for cdict in my_list if cdict["task"] == key)
```